# Sound stops after 2-5 seconds when playing youtube videos in Firefox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, audio, flash

The sound of Youtube videos stop after 2-5 seconds. The video also stops playing. I searched with Google for this problem, but I can only find solutions to other Firefox/Flash/Sound problems.

I use Firefox 3.5 and Flash 10.0.22.87 on Ubuntu 9.04. Please help.

Comment: Almost sounds like it's buffering. Or having trouble buffering, at least.

Comment: There was probably something broken in my system, which was fixed with a reboot. I feel a bit stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that problem once on Windows/Firefox, and solved the issue by reinstalling Flash. YMMV.

Comment: I removed all flashplugin files, then reinstalled flash. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

Could you try watching Youtube video's in a different browser like Opera?

That would help us determine if it's a Firefox problem.

Else you could do the same for Flash, by testing flash content on the Adobe website or installing an older version and see what version broke it.

Comment: I tried watching some streaming content from Twit on http://live.twit.tv/ The strange thing is this thing just goes on and on.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the page and clear your cache (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).

If you start the video and then pause to buffer, hit the pause button only after you see some of the red in the bar. Then wait for it to load up the rest of the video before playing. See if that fixes up the problem.

Comment: I checked this, it's not this kind of problem.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem, when my ubuntu also had /tmp mounted as an overflow device ...  (/tmp had a limit of about 1mb) which seems to break a lot of stuff.

First solve the problem that makes ubuntu mount its freaky /tmp ... then reboot.

Don't know if it's related, but it solved the problem for me.